# Azure: Route subdomain traffic to different backend port

Tags: azure, azure-application-gateway, azure-traffic-manager, azure-front-door

I have multiple sites hosted on the same machine in Azure on different ports:

```
foobar.com:8000
foobar.com:8001
foobar.com:8002
```

etc

I would like to address these by subdomain using a reverse proxy;

```
aaaa.mysite.com ----> foobar.com:8000
bbbb.mysite.com ----> foobar.com:8001
cccc.mysite.com ----> foobar.com:8002
```

Is it possible to do this in Application Gateway? It only seems to cater for different paths (not subdomains) and doesn't allow ports to be specified for backends.

Is there another Azure feature that allows for this (e.g. Front Door)?

Answer (score 2):

As your requirement to address them by subdomains in APP GW, you could use [multi-site hosting.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/multiple-site-overview)

> There are three common mechanisms for enabling multiple site hosting
>   on the same infrastructure.
>
> Host multiple web applications each on a unique IP address. Use host
>   name to host multiple web applications on the same IP address. **Use
>   different ports to host multiple web applications on the same IP
>   address.**

For example, you want `aaaa.mysite.com ----> foobar.com:8000`. The main configuration will be like this: create a multi-site listener, use frontend port **80** and hostname `aaaa.mysite.com` in this multi-site listener. HTTP setting should specify the port **8000**. Make sure the listener is listening on port 80 and HTTP setting configure your custom port for your backend websites.

In this case, you will create 3 Listeners with on same port 80,and specify the hostnames and create 3 HTTP settings, and create rules with corresponding Listener and HTTP settings and backend pool.

The Azure front door also has URL-based routing and Multiple-site hosting ability. Refer to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/front-door-overview).

### Update

### *Backend pools*

Create one backend pool and set your Azure VM as the backend in the backend pool.

### *Listeners*

Click `multi-site` to create a multi-site listener then save it. You need three listeners for your host name.
[image]
Type the subdomains as the host name
[image]

### *Health probes*

Add a health probe and checkbox `pick host name from backend http settings`.
[image]

### *HTTP settings*

Add three HTTP settings and specify the custom port on each of HTTP settings.
[image]

### *Rules*

Add three basic rules with corresponding Listener and HTTP settings and backend pool.
[image]

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't configure the AG based on your description. I tried Azure Front Door and it was much simpler to configure - just a frontend, backend and routing rule with the host name in it.

Comment: Please follow my update, let me know if this works on your side. You may refer to [this sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/scripts/create-vmss-powershell) if you want to create AG with Powershell.