# Azure: Route traffic from different subdomains and URLs to different backend ports

Tags: azure, azure-application-gateway, azure-traffic-manager, azure-front-door

I have multiple sites hosted on the same machine in Azure on different ports:

```
contoso.com:8000
contoso.com:8001
contoso.com:8002
contoso.com:8003
```

and single sites hosted on separate machines:

```
foo.com:8000
foo2.com:8000
```

I would like to address these by different URLs and different subdomains using a reverse proxy;

```
w1.fabrikam.com/I1 -> contoso.com:8000
w1.fabrikam.com/I2 -> contoso.com:8001
w2.fabrikam.com -> foo.com:8000
w3.fabrikam.com -> foo2.com:8000
```

There is a similar post to this that was answered but used subdomains only.  Is it possible to use subdomains as well as URL rules with application gateway?

[Azure: Route subdomain traffic to different backend port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57552417/azure-route-subdomain-traffic-to-different-backend-port)

Comment: Any update in this question? Does the reply help you?

Answer (score 1):

To address different subdomains to different backends, you can configure multiple-sites listener for each backends:

```
w2.fabrikam.com -> foo.com:8000
w3.fabrikam.com -> foo2.com:8000
```

For this, you could create two backend pools, and create two multi-hosting listeners.

You could refer to
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/multiple-site-overview
and
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/create-multiple-sites-portal

To address these by different URLs, you could configure path-based routing rules.

```
w1.fabrikam.com/I1 -> contoso.com:8000
w1.fabrikam.com/I2 -> contoso.com:8001
```

For the `Path-based routing`, select `Add multiple targets to create a path-based rule`. For `Path`, type `/I1/*` or `/I2/*`.

For the HTTP settings, create two HTTP settings, select the backend port `8000` or `8001` for each HTTP settings.

You could refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/create-url-route-portal